# Same eigenvalue spectrum with different matrices

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations, block-matrices, eigenfunctions

There are two matrices $D$ and $T$ which provides eigenvalue spectrum (dispersion relation) according to 
$$
E(K) = \operatorname{eig}(D + T \exp(iK) + T' \exp(-iK))
$$
$$
K = 0:dK:\pi
$$
Where K is a list of real numbers from 0 to $\pi$ spaced by $dK$. Is it possible to find 2 new matrices $d$ and $t$ with much smaller size, such that in some range of spectrum ($E_1 < Eigenvalues < E_2)$, we can reconstruct the old dispersion ($E(K)$)?
$$
e(K) = \operatorname{eig}(d + t \exp(iK) + t' \exp(-iK)) \approx E(K)
$$
$$
E_1 < E < E_2
$$
Note $T'$ is the conjugate transpose of $T$.

Comment: Is $T'$ intended as the Hermitean conjugate of $T$? Otherwise its definition is unclear.

Comment: Yes, $T'$ is the conjugate transpose of $T$.

Comment: Ok. I imagine that $D$ is a Hermitean matrix as well. Can you say anything else about their form?

Comment: D is Hermitean matrix but not T. They are very sparse. I will put a link to sparsity pattern.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/892723/block-diagonalizing-two-matrices-simultaneously?noredirect=1#comment1868194_892723

Comment: That'll be tricky to diagonalize exactly. Though, depending on the type of problem you're doing you may be able to obtain some good 'semiclassical' type results analytically. (That more or less amounts to a tight-binding model of the atomic lattice with the energy bandwidth determined by overlap integrals.)

Comment: Exactly, :) however it is orthogonal tight binding with overlap = Identity. How to get that "semiclassical" result?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16617/discussion-between-semiclassical-and-hesam).